# How do I install RTL8821AE driver for Ubuntu 20 LTS

Tags: realtek, realtek-wireless

Seems like https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git no longer exists, anyone got alternative method?

Comment: The RTL8821AE and the RTL8821CE use the same driver.  It is in the repository as `sudo apt install rtl8821ce-dkms`

Comment: Same problem here. `rtl8821ce-dkms` did not work for me.

Comment: @Rutrus Please start your own new question and include the result of: `sudo dkms status` as well as: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an equivalent repository you should look into [rtlwifi-linux/rtlwifi_new](https://github.com/rtlwifi-linux/rtlwifi_new)

It throws some warning-errors and I couldn't compile it.

**NOTE:** `rtl8821ae` driver is supported in *linux kernel* version 3 and newer, but not working properly in my case.